# Ubuntu does not support SMBIOS 3.0?

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, 15.10

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 64b in UEFI mode on my Asus F555UB (i5 6200u Skylake, nVidia 940M) and in the field where you enter the name of your pc was this:

> SMBIOS-implementations-newer-than-version-2.8-are-not-fully-supported-
> by-this-version-of-dmidecode

I clicked next and saw this errors under the progress of the installation

> PCIe Bus Error: severity = Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
>
> DEVICE [8086:9d15] error status/mask 00000001/00000000

The installation was successful and I can boot into Ubuntu but my virtual terminal is flooded with error messages which I believe are the same/similar to the errors I got during installation (I am not sure because the errors appear and change so quickly I can't read them).

I guess it is caused by the version of *SMBIOS* (the version in my laptop is 3.0) and I'd like to ask if this really is caused by the *SMBIOS*.

(one of the solutions I googled is pcie_aspm = off, but I don't want to start typing commands into my laptop and create new problems before I read your answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit grub as follows:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Replace the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash loglevel=3 vga=current pcie_aspm=off"
```

then SAVE & EXIT

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

** Enjoy this could stop the flood messages.**

Comment: I don't have time to test this solution but I'd like to thank you for your exhaustive answer. I'll sure test it in the future. Thanks!!!